# Connection timed out on apache2 ssl

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, webserver, apache2

I am trying to get a secured connection on Apache2 working but i am having a hard time. The operating system is a new install of Ubuntu 18.04 (reinstalled today as i have been running around in circles trying to eliminate reasons this isn't working).

I can get http working, and https works using internal ip address only. External ip address gives me connection timed out.

The content i was trying to serve was a php application but at the moment i am using a single html page with one line of text until i can get this working.

Here are my VirtualHost settings.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/http
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                DocumentRoot /var/www/http

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/cloudflare/ocdev.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/cloudflare/ocdev.key
                SSLCACertificateFile /etc/cloudflare/origin.pem

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>

                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have enabled ssl using `a2enmod ssl` command.

Happy to provide any more information if it will help.
Please assist!

Comment: *"https works using internal ip address only. External ip address gives me connection timed out."* - since internal IP work this is a firewall issue and not a configuration problem of Apache. Have a look at the configuration of the firewall on your machine and at possible firewalls between this machine and the browser.

Comment: Ahaha yes you are right. It is a home server and i didn't port forward 443 from my router to my server.